# Load list of images in sequential order

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, caching, onload

I'm working on a website which uses ExpressionEngine to create a list of images with img1, img2, img3 etc as the ID and creates an array with their sources imgAddresses[1], imgAddresses[2], imgAddresses[3] etc.

I'm attempting to create a function which loads the first image, then (when the first is completely loaded), load the second, third etc. The following is what I have so far:

```
function loadImage(counter) {
    var i = document.getElementById("img"+counter);
    if(counter==imgAddresses.length) { return; }
    i.onload = function(){
        loadImage(counter+1)
    }; 
    i.src = imgAddresses[counter];
} 
document.onload=loadImage(0);
```

It works when refreshing the page, but not when accessing the page via the URL. As far as I can tell from research, this is because the onload event is not fired when a cached image is loaded, and refreshing the page clears the cache, whereas accessing the page via the URL does not.

Research suggests that assigning the src of the image after declaring the onload event would get around this, but it does not seem to have solved it in this case. I was thinking that this may be because the onload event is recursive in this case.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make sure the browser is loaded a fresh copy of the image, rather than a cached version? Or whether there is a better way to write this function? Thanks for any help!

EDIT: One solution that I have found is to change the img source assignment to:

```
i.src = imgAddresses[counter] + '?' + new Date().getTime();
```

This forces the user to load a fresh copy each time, which I guess is not so much a solution, but a workaround

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can say is that you are not attaching the `document.onload` handler correctly. I cannot tell if it will fix your issue because `image.onload` is not reliable in all browsers, however the `onload` should be set to a function reference and that's not what you are doing.

Instead, you should have something like:

```
function loadImage(counter) {
    //initialize the counter to 0 if no counter was passed
    counter = counter || 0;
    var i = document.getElementById("img"+counter);
    if(counter==imgAddresses.length) { return; }
    i.onload = function(){
        loadImage(counter+1)
    }; 
    i.src = imgAddresses[counter];
}

document.onload = loadImage; //instead of loadImage(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell how the browser will manage the cached resources
Take a look to HTML5 cache approach:

- [HTML5: The cache manifest file](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)

This way you can avoid the browser cache for the specified resources.